# Constantly updating URL in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension and I want the URL to be read and written on to the extension and update as the user changes page. As Google has a content security policy in place, I've had to create a string of the URL before presenting it on the extension.

The URL is read once but is reading the URL of the extension rather than a webpage and is updating as the extension URL.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
  }
const mybox = document.querySelector('#URLbox');
const pageurl = window.location.href;
const body = document.querySelector('#body');
const ptag = document.createElement('p');
mybox.appendChild(ptag);
setInterval(function() {
  let stringurl = window.location.href.toString();
  ptag.innerHTML = stringurl;
}, 1000);
```

I was expecting the string to update every second, and therefore would capture any URL changes however it reads the URL of the extension rather than a webpage and is updating as the extension URL.

Comment: If this code is inside the action popup, it's a separate page and its location.href is chrome-extension://, in which case to observe the web page URL you need to listen to chrome.tabs.onUpdated event and `tabs` permission in manifest.json.